# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: запятая

Своими впечатлениями о Половинкине, как поэте и человеке, поделилась активная участница Лите ратурной гостиной. Мне почему-то кажется , что в этом предложении запятые не нужны, как выступает в значении "в качестве".Правильно ли я считаю.Поделитесь своими знаниями. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы абсолютно правы. Здесь запятые не нужны

Comment: Спасибо, что развеяли мои сомнения.